# How to resolve "unknown field "backoffLimit" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec"?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to limit the number of pod restarts by using the `backoffLimit` parameter, but I am getting this below error:

```
error: error validating "STDIN": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec): unknown field "backoffLimit" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Below is my `deployment.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "out-service.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}

spec:
  backoffLimit: 2
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
```

Please let me know, if I am missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`backoffLimit` is not a Kubernetes deployment object parameter. That's the reason for this error. Unfortunately, you cannot limit the pod restart count. However, you can control this behaviour using `restartPolicy` parameter for the pod spec.

Just to let you know, You can specify `backoffLimit` with Kubernetes Jobs which creates Pods and will continue to retry execution of the Pods until a specified number(backoffLimit) of them successfully terminates.